# Помогите понять работу с пост запросами в SpringMVC да и в целом

Tags: java, post, spring-mvc

Такой вопрос. Если он глуп - не минусуйте пожалуйста, просто напишите и я удалю.

У меня есть контроллер и JSP страница в проекте  SpringMVC. это весь проект. тестовый. Вот на странице есть форма с какими-то полями. я заполняю эту форму данными и отпраляю(данные в скрытом виде) на другую страницу. И вот эта другая страница, не моя вообще, сторонняя. ну вот пример

```
form method="post" action="https://host/someMethod">
    <input type="text" name="clientid" value="${clientid}"/>
    <input type="text" name="storetype" value="${storetype}"/>
    <input type="text" name="rnd" value="${rnd}"/>
    <input type="text" name="storekey" value="${storekey}"/>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
    </p>
</form>
```

Так вот отправляю я все это сюда `action="https://host/someMethod"` 
К слову это страница платежной системы. Я отправляю данные и она меня должна при успехе перенаправить на другую страницу дозаполнения данных, опять же не мною реализованную, а при ошибке на страницу с ошибкой, которую реализую я(она передается как параметр, эта моя страница, при отправке этой формы).

Так вот, Я старницу отправляю, с данными, а получаю ошибку. Но увидеть ее не могу. Просто меня перенаправляет на страницу, которую я указал при отправке, как ошибочную и все. Я хочу отловить, все что мне приходит ответом от этого сервиса.

Я тправил форму, получил респонс, вот я и хочу его узнать, вывести, в дебагере поймать  итд. чтоб ошибку отловить.

Я сделал иначе, и отправил на эту же ссылку с этими параметрами запрос, но не как форму а из кода,  post запросом.

```
 public void sendPost() throws IOException {
        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://host/someMethod");

// Request parameters and other properties.
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("clientid", clientid));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("storetype", storetype));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rnd", rnd));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("storekey", storekey));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));

//Execute and get the response.
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            try {
                // do something useful
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));
                String line;
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
                System.out.println(buffer.toString());
            } finally {
                instream.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

и вот тут в мой `buffer` вывелся код страницы, которая приходит в ответ. А приходит другая форма, с джава скриптом и тд, тоесть полноценная страница(показать не могу в целях конфидециальности), но она приходит. А при отправке запроса формой, страница не приходит. просто перенаправляет на несуществующую страницу, которую я указал как ошибосчную. В общем сам вопрос

1. Могу ли я отловить респонс на пост запрос на стороннюю страницу? если да то как.
2. Как отправить в чем разница отправки пост запрос ас формы и из кода?
3. как отправить пост запрос, а потом вывести в браузере ответ(я знаю точно что он приходит)?

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вопрос не имеет отношения к Spring MVC, да и к Java в целом. Это вопрос по архитектуре Web 2.0 и HTTP протоколу.

> Могу ли я отловить респонс на пост запрос на стороннюю страницу?

Почитайте про [кросс-доменные запросы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0). Нелья через форму принадлежащую одному домену, обратиться к другому дрмену. Это можно сделать через [AJAX](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX) и [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) или [JSONP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

> Как отправить в чем разница отправки пост запрос ас формы и из кода

Если под отправкой "из кода" вы имеете в виду использование Java HttpClient - нет разницы. Вы можете открыть консоль браузера, посмотреть какие он отправляет HTTP заголовки, и переписать их в HttpClient. HttpClient, в данном случае, и есть ваш браузер.

> как отправить пост запрос, а потом вывести в браузере ответ

Разберитесь какой запрос вы хотите отправить - AJAX или не AJAX. В первом случае обработка ответа происходит в обработчике (success, error); во втором - ответ сервера и есть та страница, которая должна быть отображена в браузере - от вас ничего не требуется.

Если вы подключатесь к платежной системе, то у вас должно быть соответствующее API, которое предоставляется системой, и описание как им пользоваться. Ничего своего изобретать не нужно, и не получится.